# Ubuntu USB connection Problem

Tags: usb, connection, development, ls, lsusb

The usb connection is confirmed in the Ubuntu terminal command "lsusb", but not in command "ls /dev".

I expected "ttyXXX" format, but I can not confirm it.

++++++ edit ++++++++

[This image is that The usb connection is confirmed in the Ubuntu terminal command "lsusb"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1E5t.png)
─────[i]

[This image is that The usb connection is confirmed in the Ubuntu terminal command "ls /dev"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnkM.jpg)
─────[ii]

*** cf) My USB is CrazyRadio PA (to connect crazyflie 2.0)

Questions] 
In the general case, USB connection is confirmed in both cases [i] and [ii]. However, "CrazyRadio PA" USB is confirmed in [i] but not in [ii].
I want to check "CrazyRadio PA" USB connection in the form "ttyXXX"(like ttyACM0) in [ii].

Comment: Please explain with more details what you have and what you want. What is your problem?

Comment: When I connect the USB, I can confirm that USB is connected through the Ubuntu terminal command "lsusb". However, the USB connection can not be confirmed through the terminal command "ls / dev". What I want is USB recognition in the form of "ttyACM0", "ttyS10", "ttyUSB0". More specifically, when USB is connected, there must be something in the "/ dev" directory to add the device's directory.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please [edit] your question to provide the details there instead of here in the comments where this crucial information can get lost (cc @sudodus)

Comment: What kind of USB device is it? Is it a USB pendrive or some other kind of device, that you connect via USB? - and I agree with Fabby: Please edit your question and include all the details there.

Comment: @Fabby  i'm sorry, i can write English very well, becaus i am Korean Student.. So i carry image and edit my Question!

Comment: @sudodus i'm sorry, i can write English very well, becaus i am Korean Student.. So i carry image and edit my Question!

Comment: I suggest that you ask at the "CrazyRadio PA" web site, if their product works with Ubuntu (or linux at all), and in that case what you should do. - But maybe is works only with Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Crazyradio PA does not implement serial port over USB protocol. It uses a custom USB protocol by talking directly to the endpoint using libusb. This is why you will not find it detected as a serial port.

If you want to verify that a USB device has been recognized you can type "dmesg" just after inserting the USB device, you will then see what, if any, kernel driver is handling this device (for example serial, audio, ...).

The Crazyradio USB protocol and python library are described in the bitcraze wiki: https://wiki.bitcraze.io/doc:crazyradio:index. If all you want is to control a Crazyflie, the Crazyflie client and lib will use any inserted Crazyradio PA.

Disclaimer: I am part of Bitcraze and the main Crazyradio developper.

Comment: thanks your help, i go to "https://wiki.bitcraze.io/doc:crazyradio:index" and, apply to my project by using information at wiki. Have a nice day!

Comment: i want to get mavros fcu_url of "Crazyradio PA " , i can do it?